# DiscordJS and php linking

Tags: php, node.js, paypal

I am making a Discord bot that has a where it generates a payment link and once you pay it sends a message saying Paid in the chat. I have seen it done before so I know it's possible and I have the basics done but I am getting stuck on something. I use the Paypal-express-checkout npm addon and when you run -pay (amount0) it generated a payment link for the amount given but when it returns to my return URL which is confirm.php it has the variables in the URL but I don't know how to send them to the node.js application or for the node.js applicaiton to fetch them so it can confirm that it was actually made. There are 2 functions with the addon that I use, one of them creates the link and one of them confirms it hence why I need the variables sent to the php file.

Thanks

```
paypal.pay(message.id, args[0], 'Invoice', 'USD', function(err, url) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        message.channel.send({embed: {
          color: 0x28d651,
          title: "Slashy Payment",
          fields: [
            {
              name: "Invoice Amount",
              value: "$" + args[0],
              inline: true
            },
            {
              name: "Invoice Client",
              value: message.author.username,
              inline: true
            },
            {
              name: "Invoice Status",
              value: "Pending..."
            },
            {
              name: "Payment Link",
              value: '[Pay here](' + url + ')'
            }
          ],
          timestamp: new Date(),
          footer: {
            icon_url: bot.user.avatarURL,
            text: "© Slashy 2018"
          }
        }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone wanting to know how I managed to do it in the end just store the message.channel.id in the URL for the paypal return link and when they get to the page save the info into a database with the channel id and just keep checking the database every 5 seconds in the channel if the item has been marked as paid in the database. Really cool fix that seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution for you, instead of polling, just create an express webserver or open a tcp socket. Yes php does tcp sockets as well. Anyways, once paypal returns its message to your php server, have the php script send a request to your node.js express server that is also running your bot. I don't know how option people will be purchasing via your bot, but it seems like a good alternative than to waste some cpu time if loads of people start buying :D but hey, that's a good problem right?